# array.select n elements at most

Tags: ruby, arrays, collections

Consider a Ruby array with **a lot** of elements.

I want to reverse iterate over the array and select the first n results for which a given block returns true.

E.g.

```
seniors = persons.reverse.select do |person|
  person.age > 60
end
```

This is okay, however it collects all seniors, instead of n seniors at most. What's the nicest way to prematurely terminate the iteration when n results has been collected?

Comment: is seniors = seniors.first(n) an option, instead of prematurely terminating?

Comment: You could just call `.take(n)` after `end`

Comment: @user2864740 that's not true.  For the array `[1,2,3,61].take(3)` will exclude `61` which should be included in the result set

Comment: @user2864740, your example slices n elements and then selects from those, right? That's not what I'm looking to do. I want to select n elements at most, not select from n elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
seniors = []
persons.reverse.each{ |p| 
  seniors << p if p.age > 60
  break if seniors.count >= n
}
```

Comment: I don't think that the `reverse` actually does anything either, but it depends on what the input array is

Comment: This will do it. If the `seniors` array is very large, I might also keep track of its size in a separate count variable rather than calling `.count` on every iteration.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but to my understanding, the Array Datatype already keeps track of its count itself.

Comment: @jmromer, I just created an array with half a million random strings and 1000 times puts the count and it printed instantly, so the count method does not exhibit linear performance.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, `reverse` takes about 10 ms to run in my irb session for an array with half a million random strings.

Comment: @NielsB. there are more considerations than just performance.  Someone who has to update your code may be confused by the useless `reverse`

Comment: @ExplosionPills, why do think `reverse` is useless? I need to select from the end.

Comment: @christian.buggle, [you are right](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#label-Obtaining+Information+about+an+Array) -- this is good to know, thanks.

Comment: @NielsB., instead of reversing and then iterating, you can also just iterate in reverse order using [`Array#reverse_each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse_each)

Answer (score 2):

[Lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) is great because it makes possible to write this kind of code without changing the abstractions you would normally use in strict evaluation (Haskell has proved how powerful this is). Happily Ruby 2.0 will ship with some infrastructure on this regard, when that time comes you'll be able to write this:

```
# Ruby >= 2.0
seniors = persons.reverse.lazy.select { |person| person.age > 60 }.take(n)
```

For Ruby < 2.0: https://github.com/yhara/enumerable-lazy

Answer (score 1):

You can chain `take_while` and `each_with_object`:

```
seniors = []
persons.take_while.each_with_object(seniors) do |e, o| 
  o << e if e.age > 60 && o.count < 1000
  o.count < 1000
end

require 'ostruct'
require 'benchmark'

persons = 1000000.times.map {|i| OpenStruct.new age: Random.rand(50..85) }

Benchmark.bm do |b|
  b.report do
    seniors = []
    persons.take_while.each_with_object(seniors) do |e, o| 
      o << e if e.age > 60 && o.count < 1000
      o.count < 1000
    end
  end
end

#=> finishes in 1-3ms on my machine
```